# SQL: Joining 3 tables with count, addition, and more restrictions

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

Hei guys I'm really stuck on this problem. I want to get the total quantity (QT) which is Q1+Q2-Q3 with each Q(n) came from different tables.

I have 3 tables

```
tables:  STOCKURP    REPORTENABLEURP    RECHARGE
FK    :  code        code               accountid
```

Each tables have different amount of QUANTITY for each CREDIT, the first two tables, STOCKURP and REPORTENABLEURP, already have QUANTITY stored in them, while for the RECHARGE table, I have to count it first.

To give you an easier understanding I'll divide this thing by parts.

**Part 1: 2 Quantities**

I want to get a list of the 2 quantities of all of the items in the 2 tables.
This is my query:

```
select stockurp.code as CODE, stockurp.credit, stockurp.quantity as Q1, reportenableurp.qty as Q2
from stockurp join reportenableurp 
on stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code and stockurp.credit = reportenableurp.credit 
where stockurp.date = '20150930' and reportenableurp.date = '2015-09-30'
```

With that, I get this

```
CODE  CREDIT   Q1   Q2
12    15000    12   566
12    20000    24   341
43    15000    343  400
43    20000    12   65
46    50000    78   102
```

**Part 2: Counting the Q3**

To get the third quantity (Q3), I have to count how many occurrences does an ACCOUNTID have for each CREDIT.
My query is like this:

```
select accountid, credit, count (recharge.credit) as Q3
from recharge
group by accountid, credit
```

The result is this:

```
ACCOUNTID   CREDIT   Q3
   12       15000    20
   12       20000    301
   45       15000    65
   67       50000    9
```

**Part 3: QT The total quantity**

QT = Q1 + Q2 - Q3

To do so, I have to join the 3 tables and I cant seem to find a way to do this. I've tried multiple ways like:

```
select stockurp.code as CODE, stockurp.credit, Q1, Q2
from 
     (
    select count (recharge.credit) as Q3
    from recharge
    group by accountid, credit
    )
join 
    (
    select stockurp.quantity as Q1, reportenableurp.qty as Q2
    from stockurp join reportenableurp   
    on stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code and stockurp.credit = reportenableurp.credit 
    where stockurp.tanggal = '20150930' and reportenableurp.tanggal = '2015-09-30'
    )

on stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code
```

Yeah I know, that query is stupid, lol.. I just cant find the right mindset to get the solution. The end result should be like this:

```
CODE  CREDIT   Q1   Q2   Q3   QT
12    15000    12   566  34   544
12    20000    24   341  124  241
43    15000    343  400  87   656
43    20000    12   65   50   27
46    50000    78   102  11   169
```

Can you guys help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way:

```
SELECT table1.CODE,table1.credit, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q1 + Q2 - Q3 total_result
FROM
(select stockurp.code as CODE, stockurp.credit, stockurp.quantity as Q1, reportenableurp.qty as Q2
from stockurp join reportenableurp 
on stockurp.code = reportenableurp.code and stockurp.credit = reportenableurp.credit 
where stockurp.date = '20150930' and reportenableurp.date = '2015-09-30')
table1
JOIN
(select accountid, credit, count (recharge.credit) as Q3
from recharge
group by accountid, credit) table2
ON table1.CODE=table2.accountid
AND table1.credit=table2.credit
```